# Two activities and different case for onResume method

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onresume

My problem is I have two `activities` A and B, and 1 `function` in the `acitivity B`.

In `activity A` , if I click on a `button` it will call : `this.finish()`, then I will be in the second `activity`  i.e. `ActivityB` and with the`onResume()` it will execute my `function B : onResume() { functionB}`

The thing i want to use `functionB` after this case.
So I wonder if it's possible to know (when using `onResume()`) , from "where you come" : So If i get `onResume()` from another `activity` that is not A, It would never use `function B`, but It will use only B if I finish `ActivityA`

Hope you understand.

Thank you

Comment: just add a boolean to your intent which is true when coming from A and otherwise it is false. if you are calling A from B, then you should use the onActivityResult method.

Comment: The things is that I do not use intent from A to B, they are both initialize, then when I finished my tasks with A, I call this.finish and I will be back to B with onResume. Maybe I did not understand you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`. Like so:

```
startActivityForResult(activityIntent, 100);
```

Then instead of calling this.finish() you would call:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
this.finish();
```

Then in your resuming Activity this method will get called before onResume:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

Here you can set some kind of `boolean` variable to true to let the `Activity` know that it has come from your other `Activity` then in onResume check to see if the `boolean` is set to true, if it is do whatever you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SharedPreferences for this to work like in your scenario.

in your ActivityA. do somthing like this against your buttonClick before you call finish();

```
SharedPreferences sp = ActivityA.this.getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sp.edit();
sp.putBoolean("from" , true);
sp.commit();
```

then in your ActivityB's onResume do it like this.

```
SharedPreferences sp = ActivityB.this.getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(sp.getBoolean("from",false))
{ 
// write your code here . it is from activirt A.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to achieve your requirement.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putBoolean(key,value); 
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent); // This passes the information to your activity
```

Receive the information in your activity by using

```
boolean value = getIntent().getExtras().putBoolean(key);
```

Using `value` you can come to know whether its calling from `onResume` or from some where.

Hope that helps

Comment: This would be an acceptable answer for passing data from one `Activity` to another. But the question was how to let one `Activity` know if it has come back from another via finishing the second one.